# Multi-tenant DB Design, a Salesforce scenario

Tags: database, database-design, salesforce, multi-tenant

I was doing some research into the optimal DB setup for a Salesforce like application (webapp with sensitive data for multiple 10.000's of customers, each customer can have **multiple USER** accounts).

My idea is, is that the split database setup (different DB for each customer) is the best since its the only way to make sure data is really isolated in terms of security, and because its not just multi customer, but each customer can have multiple users that login to work on the data. However...is having a DB instance with 10.000 'small' DB's really gonna work?

I dont really feel much for the shared schema setup since you will end up with 10's of thousands of tables, which doesn't seem very manageable.

The 1 big DB setup with just using a customerID column per table seems the easiest to implement, but not really secure...and joining tables will be quite a task as I presume.

What are your thoughts on this scenario? The seperate DB's-scenario seems best to me from a scalability and security perspective...but what do I know :D

Thanks!

Comment: You don't have to use a single instance. You could run 100 different instances on 100 different servers if you wanted to. Base your decision on research and testing, not on your feelings and presumptions. Feelings and presumptions don't scale well.

Comment: which database? a mysql "database" is different than a postgres "database" for example.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, you can opt to use a different database for each tenant or for a set of tenants. That will give better scalability, good data access speeds, security compliance etc.. In case you have to do a tenant data back up, it is faster and can be automated. 
The one consideration would be in accessing the data from both the shared and the shared database..

Even each tenant can opt to have a separate database for maintaining the user info so that the basic tenant authentication will come from the shared db and further the separate db can be used to authenticate the users.
Please share your thoughts on this.

Comment: You will still end up with a billion small DB's for each tenant and 1 bigger DB for shared data. I'd assume that having 1 big db can work with partitioning when its needed...

Comment: It is not the case, in the case of a shared database, you will have the basic authentication and authorization data. The separate tenants or the subtree's of the tenants in the hierarchy will have their separate databases.